# Comparação entre número aleatório e número digitado nunca diz que acertou, mesmo os números sendo iguais

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer um programa no qual eu possa digitar um número `n` e em seguida gostaria de gerar um numero aleatório entre 1 e 2. Se esse numero aleatório for o mesmo que `n`, mostraria "Você ganhou!" e, senão, "Você perdeu". Porém, mesmo ao acertar o número, está aparecendo "Você perdeu!".

Segue aí o meu código. Obrigado.

```
from random import randint

n = (input('Digite um número: '))  
print (randint( 1, 2))  
if n == (randint):  
    print ('Você ganhou!')  
else:  
    print ('Você perdeu!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz

```
if n == (randint):
```

você está comparando o `n` com `randint`, que é uma função e não o valor sorteado (note que funções são objetos em Python). Essa comparação sempre vai dar negativa no seu caso.

Salve o valor sorteado numa variável pra poder comparar depois. Por exemplo:

```
numero_sorteado = randint(1, 2)
```

E, na hora da comparação, fique atento aos tipos. a função `input()` retorna uma string, então converta pra um número com a função `int` antes de comparar:

```
n = int(input('Digite um número: '))  
numero_sorteado = randint(1, 2)
print(numero_sorteado)  
if n == numero_sorteado:  
    print ('Você ganhou!')  
else:  
    print ('Você perdeu!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é isto que você quer:

```
from random import randint
if int(input('Digite um número: ')) == randint( 1, 2):
    print ('Você ganhou!')
else:
    print ('Você perdeu!')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QEPkqI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qzetbzzz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/Converting.py).

Não fez a conversão de `string` para `int` na entrada de dados e não guardou o número aleatório gerado em variável para testar depois. Esse código ainda é um pouco falho, mas funciona na maioria das vezes, por hora acho que está bom, afinal está aprendendo de forma pouco estruturada e não vai longe assim.

Answer (score 0):

Então, do jeito que está o seu código a comparação feita pelo 'if' é basicamente de uma string (representação em texto, nesse caso de um número 1 ou 2), com um inteiro (o número em si e não uma representção dele):

```
if n == (randint)
```

Com o detalhe de que, como não há uma variável armazenando o primeiro **randint**, você está basicamente executando um método **randint 'x'**(gerando um resultado 'x'), mostrando esse método **'x'** para o usuário, e depois executando um método **'randint' 'y'**, e usando esse para a comparação com o input do usuário.

Então sugiro armazenar o 'randint' em uma váriavel do tipo int(inteiro), mostrar essa variável armazenda para o usuário e usa-la na comparação.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando as outras respostas. Você também pode utilizar um [operador ternário](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html#ternary-operators) para completar esta rotina de verificar o número com o número sorteado e simplificar um pouco mais o código, veja abaixo:

```
from random import randint

print("Você ganhou!") if int(input("Numero: ")) == randint(1, 2) else print("Você perdeu!")
```

A sintaxe deste operador é o seguinte

```
x if condicao else y
```

No caso da condição `int(input("Numero: ")) == randint(1, 2)` ser verdadeira a instrução ao lado esquerdo do `if` sera executada, caso contrário, a instrução a ser executada sera do comando `else`.

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/NauticalFatObjectcode).